# AWS Codestar Laravel EB - Artisan File Incorrect

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-artisan

I have created a new Codestar Project using the Laravel Template with Elastic Beanstalk. After opening the Cloud9 IDE and navigating to the project root it appears the artisan file is incorrect.

This may be a misunderstanding of mine but I cannot see anywhere that documents a process required for the artisan after creating from a template.

I have replicated this process 2-3 times to ensure setup was not corrupt.

```
j_boswood:~/environment/iactionportal (master) $ php artisan list
PHP Warning:  require(/home/ec2-user/environment/iactionportal/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ec2-user/environment/iactionportal/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/ec2-user/environment/iactionportal/artisan:0
PHP   2. require() /home/ec2-user/environment/iactionportal/artisan:16
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/ec2-user/environment/iactionportal/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/ec2-user/environment/iactionportal/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/ec2-user/environment/iactionportal/artisan:0
PHP   2. require() /home/ec2-user/environment/iactionportal/artisan:16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I needed to run `curl -sS getcomposer.org/installer | php` to install composer then run `php composer.phar install --ignore-platform-reqs` to install the preconfigured vendor items. –